# Mysql (trigger), when inserting data changing it using another table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have two tables:

```
item                         
------------
1.id                            
2.name                          
3.price                 
------------                 

client_item
------------
1.id
2.client
3.item
4.price
------------
```

When inserting data into the `client_item` table, inserting only an item and client, I need to update the price automatically using 'item' table.

Something like this:

```
SET NEW.price = (SELECT price from item where aid=NEW.item);
```

Comment: how would we be helping you do it ?

Comment: This might give some idea: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93723/how-can-we-select-data-from-another-table-during-an-insert

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you need to set the price of the item, rather than joining the `item` table to the `client_item` table at a later point to get the price?

Comment: "client_item" table used for create client bills , and "item" table hold the current price of the item. Simply "item" table   price can be change as user requirement.   So if i joined that two table , Client old bills can be change as to change of new price of "item" table..